# companion object as factory in scala

Tags: scala, factory, point, companion-object

I am just starting out with Scala, and working on some tutorials. I came across companion object, and using them as factory. I tried several things out. However I am not getting the following to work properly. Cant get my head around it..

```
import math._

abstract class Point{
  // ...
}
object Point{
  private class PointInt(val x:Int,val y:Int) extends Point{
    def +(that:PointInt) = new PointInt(this.x + that.x, this.y + that.y)
    def distance(that:PointInt) = 
      sqrt(pow((this.x - that.x), 2) + pow((this.y - that.y), 2))
  }
  private class PointDouble(val x:Double,val y:Double) extends Point{
    def +(that:PointDouble) = new PointDouble(this.x + that.x, this.y + that.y)
    def distance(that:PointDouble) = 
      sqrt(pow((this.x - that.x), 2) + pow((this.y - that.y), 2))
  }
  def apply(x:Int,y:Int):Point = new PointInt(x,y)
  def apply(x:Double,y:Double):Point = new PointDouble(x,y)
}

val a = Point(1,2)
val b = Point(3,4)
val c = a+b // does not work...
```

Just trying to add up two integer Points, like I defined it in the methods... Does anyone know what I am doing wrong??

**EDIT:** I was was trying to wrap the following (working) class in an Factory.

```
class Point(val x:Int,val y:Int){
  def +(that:Point) = new Point(this.x + that.x, this.y + that.y)
  def distance(that:Point) = sqrt(pow((this.x - that.x),2) + pow((this.y - that.y),2))

}

val a = new Point(1,2)              //> a  : week1.OU2.Point = week1.OU2$Point@73e48fa7
val b = new Point(3,4)              //> b  : week1.OU2.Point = week1.OU2$Point@677bb8fe
val c = a+b                         //> c  : week1.OU2.Point = week1.OU2$Point@6bae60c5
c.x                                 //> res0: Int = 4
c.y                                 //> res1: Int = 6
```

Comment: Where would `a` get a `+` method from?  All it knows is that it is of type `Point`.  It _doesn't know it's actually a `PointInt`_--that's what the return type of `Point` means!  Did you mean to add a `+` method to `Point`?

Comment: In addition to Rex's comments, the `+` method would need to take a `Point`, not a subclass of `Point` if you wanted to pass a `PointInt` to a `PointDouble`.

Comment: Hi Rex, Shouldnt the apply method give a an PointInt object?

Comment: If you annotate the method with a return type, `def apply(...): Point =` then that's the type visible from the call site, even if the value returned is actually a sub type of `Point`. The call site doesn't "see" beyond the `: Point =`, so has no clue that you have a `PointInt` with a `+` method.

Comment: Ahh, That makes totally sense. So the applies should be changed to:                                                                                   def apply(x:Int,y:Int):PointInt = new PointInt(x,y); def apply(x:Double,y:Double):PointDouble = new PointDouble(x,y)? This works!

Comment: @Kevinw1983 If I'm not mistaken your last change will only work in the same file.  If you try adding the two points outside you will run into the same problem since `PointInt` and `PointDouble` are `private`.

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure which constraints are actually imposed on you, for example, which classes should/must be private, but using F-bounded polymorphism might be a stepping stone to your desired solution.

```
/* Simplified interface (adding sqrt is straight-forward) */

abstract class Point[P <: Point[P]] {
  def +(that: P): P
}

/* Two implementations */

class PointInt(val x:Int,val y:Int) extends Point[PointInt] {
  def +(that:PointInt) = new PointInt(this.x + that.x, this.y + that.y)
}

class PointDouble(val x:Double,val y:Double) extends Point[PointDouble] {
  def +(that:PointDouble) = new PointDouble(this.x + that.x, this.y + that.y)
}

/* Companion object */

object Point {
  def apply(x:Int,y:Int) = new PointInt(x,y)
  def apply(x:Double,y:Double) = new PointDouble(x,y)
}

/* Use cases */

val a = Point(1,2)
val b = Point(3,4)
val c = a+b // ok
val d = Point(1.0, 2.5)
val e = c+d // error: type mismatch
```

Notice, however, that this won't help you in case you want to hide your implementations, i.e., make them private and declare public interfaces using the generic `Point` only - as others pointed out already.